# Can any one tell me how to upload an image from asp.net to godaddy server

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;

namespace GodaddyImages
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath("~\\Images\\"));
                List<ListItem> files = new List<ListItem>();
                foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
                    files.Add(new ListItem(fileName, "~\\Images\\" + fileName));
                }
                GridView1.DataSource = files;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
        protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~\\Images\\") + fileName);
                Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can any one tell me how to upload an image from asp.net to godaddy server.
I can upload images to local folders but found difficult in uploading into godaddy server

Comment: What error are you getting? Just check the path folder (think it should be '/Images/') and also check permissions.

Comment: for your path i.e "~\\Images\\" change it to @"~\Images\"   The @ symbol means you do not have to escape the backslash as asp.net will know it is a url, which can sometimes cause issues. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically in local system you will be having permissions to writing files(Images in this case). But when you are using server( or shared hosting) typically for security purposes they will give you read-only access to the folder that you deploy. But you can go ahead and still change the permissions of it when you are admin for that domain which you have hosted.The code required for uploading from asp.net  is as straight forward as :

```
    fileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Images/") + fileUpload.FileName);
```

But, still for it work you need to have appropriate write permission for that particular folder.

Hope, it helps.